# How to sort data by months and years?

Tags: flutter, datetime

```
class Object{
DateTime dateTime;
double price;
}
Map<String,double> months;
Map<int,Map<String,double>> years;
```

I am reciving list of Objects with DateTime and price.I want to add the object first to months.And then to years.I am having trouble to made it and then this Map should be represent as Line chart.Any ideas?
I have tried to foreach every Object then to add to the months map and then to years map but it is not working.

example:

```
Object object1 = Object(DateTime(2020,10,2),2.0);
Object object2 = Object(DateTime(2020,10,2),1.0);
Object object3 = Object(DateTime(2019,10,2),1.0);
Object object4 = Object(DateTime(2020,8,2),2.0);

years = {2019:October:1,2020:October:3,2020:August:2};
```

expected:
years {2019:October:1,2020:October:3,2020:August:2}

what I tried:

```
 objects.forEach((element) {
      Map<String, double> newElement = {
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(element.date, isUtc: true).toLocal().month.toString():
            element.smsPrice
      };
      months.addAll(newElement);
      Map<int, Map<String, double>> newElement1 = {
        DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(element.date, isUtc: true).toLocal().year: newElement
      };
      years.addAll(newElement1);
    });

outcome:
years {2020:August:1,2019:October:2}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with compareTo method

```
 objects = objects.sort((a,b) {
    var adate = a['datetime'] 
     var bdate = b['datetime'] // datetime is your key
     return list.compareTo(bdate);
  });
```